# How to negate multiple filter condition at same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

example: I have a dataframe like
[image]

I want to filter multiple condition with negation `firstname == "James" & lastname == "Smith" or firstname == "Robert" & lastname == "Williams"`

my required output should be
[image]

I am using something like this but its not working

```
df = df.filter(~(df.firstname == "James") & (df.lastname == "Smith")|~(df.firstname == "Robert") & (df.lastname == "Williams"))
```

Comment: Put in words your condition please in the question body, as to what do you want to filter

Comment: i have modified is it fine? i know a logic to get the required output but i want to use negation on multiple condition using dataframe filter

Answer (score 2):

Negation of `A|B` is `(~A)&(~B)`.

So try this:

```
df = df.filter((~(firstname == "James" & lastname == "Smith")) & (~(firstname == "Robert" & lastname == "Williams")))
```

Because the negation of `C&D` is `(~C)|(~D)`, you can further simplify your filtering condition as

```
df = df.filter((firstname != "James" | lastname != "Smith") & (firstname != "Robert" | lastname != "Williams"))
```

Comment: is putting parentheses around the NOT operator (~) when selecting with multiple conditions strictly necessary? or just for readability?

Answer (score 1):

here OR condition is not giving the right output. we have to change it to AND

```
df_new = (df
          .filter(~((F.col("firstname") == "James") & (F.col("lastname") == "Smith"))
                  & ~((F.col("firstname") == "Robert") & (F.col("lastname") == "Williams"))
                 )
         )
```

results in below -

[image: Output]

Comment: negative expression in parenthesis wont work i tried and also i am looking for answer with negation of multiple conditions inside filter

Comment: I have updated my answer, check

Answer (score 1):

You will have to apply the negation on the entire condition.

```py
data = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","jim","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","60563","F",-1)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "id", "gender", "salary", ))

(df.filter(~(((df.firstname == "James") & (df.lastname == "Smith")) |
             ((df.firstname == "Robert") & (df.lastname == "Williams"))
            )
          )
   .show())
```

### Output

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|  Michael|      Rose|     jim|40288|     M|  4000|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|60563|     F|    -1|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```